# Trying to identify a military SF short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, military-sf

I'm trying to identify a short story that was part of an anthology of military science fiction.  Probably published 20 years ago or more.

Most of the stories were of the two-sides-mutually-annihilate-each-other genre.  It wasn't a hopeful anthology.

This particular story was the US vs the East (I don't remember that the other side was specifically the Soviet Union) in a bio-war that had been going on for many years.  The Earth is more-or-less barren, white clouds of unidentifiable yuck drifting around.

An exploratory spacecraft returns to Earth and finds that there is one remaining US bacteriological station.  There is no mention of the other side.  The crew makes contact on the ground wearing environmental suits.  One of their suits is later breached and the crewperson immediately dies horribly from multiple diseases.

There was a bit where the light switches in the station were too tall for the technicians working there, this was explained as the result of a genetic therapy to an attack from the other side.

It ends with one of the remaining technicians showing the Captain (?) a new engineered life form, calling it "his son/child".  An offspring that can survive in what has been done to the world, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [I Put My Blue Genes On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Put_My_Blue_Genes_On) by Orson Scott Card and is a duplicate of this existing question:

[Short story: Earth covered in germs after biological war, patriotic amoebas descended from humanity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138979/short-story-earth-covered-in-germs-after-biological-war-patriotic-amoebas-desc).

Comment: Yep.  I don't remember the name of the anthology I read it in, but OSC's _Maps in a Mirror_ is available from Amazon for 99c and I re-read it.